# Formatting numbers before taking Sum in XSL sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is My XML:

```
<OutboundPaymentInstruction>
  <OutboundPayment>
   <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>Y</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>2150.1435</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
  <OutboundPayment>
    <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>Y</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>8258.4375</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
  <OutboundPayment>
    <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>Y</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>4085.1105</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
 </OutboundPaymentInstruction>
```

This is the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="OutboundPaymentInstruction">
  <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <GrpHdr>
      <CtrlSum>
        <xsl:if test="(/OutboundPaymentInstruction/OutboundPayment/Extend2/SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT='Y')">
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(format-number(/OutboundPaymentInstruction/OutboundPayment/Extend2/BASE_AMOUNT,'#.00'))"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:if>
      </CtrlSum>
    </GrpHdr>
  </Document>
</xsl:template>
```

I want format the numbers to 2 decimal before taking the sum in XSL. For instance I want to add 2150.14,8258.43 and 4085.11 rather then their 4 decimal format.Is it possible to convert them to 2 decimal and then take their sum.Please help

---

**Added:**

This XSL was developed by someone else and later they found one bug and thats why asked me to work on this. Clearly I don't know anything about XML or XSL. Now the issue was, suppose if input amounts are 45.678 and 23.456, but in XSL we were truncating these amounts to 2 decimals and sendting to bank as 45.67 and 23.45 alongwith their sum(69.13). Now Bank is adding the individual amounts(69.12) and comparing it with the given sum(69.13). Thats why I want to format the numbers before adding them rather then after the sum.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the issue was, suppose if input amounts are 45.678 and 23.456, but
>   in XSL we were truncating these amounts to 2 decimals and sendting to
>   bank as 45.67 and 23.45 alongwith their sum(69.13). Now Bank is adding
>   the individual amounts(69.12) and comparing it with the given
>   sum(69.13).

If you want to truncate - i.e. round down<sup>1</sup> - the given amounts to 2 decimals before summing them, try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/OutboundPaymentInstruction">
    <xsl:variable name="truncated-amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="OutboundPayment/Extend2[SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT='Y']">
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="floor(100 * BASE_AMOUNT) div 100"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <GrpHdr>
            <CtrlSum>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($truncated-amounts)/amount)"/>
            </CtrlSum>
        </GrpHdr>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input:**

```
<OutboundPaymentInstruction>
  <OutboundPayment>
   <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>Y</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>45.678</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
  <OutboundPayment>
    <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>N</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>9999.9999</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
  <OutboundPayment>
    <Extend2>
      <SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>Y</SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT>
      <BASE_AMOUNT>23.456</BASE_AMOUNT>
    </Extend2>
  </OutboundPayment>
 </OutboundPaymentInstruction>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <GrpHdr>
    <CtrlSum>69.12</CtrlSum>
  </GrpHdr>
</Document>
```

---

(1) Truncating and rounding down (i.e. towards negative infinity) are the same for *positive* numbers, but not for *negative* ones. If your input can contain negative amounts, and you want to truncate them - IOW, if you always want to round towards zero - you must use `ceiling()` for negative numbers instead of `floor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<CtrlSum>
    <xsl:variable name="var">
        <xsl:for-each select="OutboundPayment/Extend2[SHOW_CONVERTED_AMOUNT='Y']/BASE_AMOUNT">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.00')"/>
            </value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($var)/value)"/>
</CtrlSum>
```

In XSLT-1.0 we need some `node-set` function. For example, from EXSLT. For that we need specify xmlns:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
```

Comment: Be careful of using `format-number()` for the purposes of *rounding*. The results can vary depending on the processor being used.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Ok, I got it. Thanks. I'm surprised by the author's desire too.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: This XSL was developed by someone else and later they found one bug and thats why asked me to work on this. Clearly I don't know anything about XML or XSL. Now the issue was, suppose if input amounts are 45.678 and 23.456, but in XSL we were truncating these amounts to 2 decimals and sendting to bank as 45.67 and 23.45 alongwith their sum(69.13). Now Bank is adding the individual amounts(69.12) and comparing it with the given sum(69.13). Thats why I want to format the numbers before adding them rather then after the sum.

Comment: @user2762553 "*it is not working*" is not a good description of a problem. You should explain what exactly is wrong. And your second comment should be added to your question. In fact, I will do so now.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0: `sum(//element/round-half-to-even(., 2))`

In XSLT 1.0, the rounding performed by `format-number()` isn't precisely specified, and that's not really what the function is for; a better way of rounding to two decimal places might be `round($x*100) div 100`. But whatever method you use, you hit the problem that in XSLT 1.0 there's no such thing as a collection of numbers, only a collection of nodes, so to sum anything that doesn't appear literally in the source document, you have to create new nodes containing the computed numbers, and to sum over these nodes you will need the `exslt:node-set()` function to turn a result tree fragment into a node-set.